# Hibernate: Inherited Superclass with Composite ID

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one JPA mapped superclass (joined inheritance strategy) that haves also a composite id class:

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(MyCompositeIdClass.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class MySuperClass {
  
  @Id
  private Long myFirstId;

  @Id
  private Long mySecondId;
}
```

```java
public class MyCompositeIdClass implements Serializable {
  private static long serialVersionUID = 1L;


  @Id
  private Long myFirstId;

  @Id
  private Long mySecondId;
}
```

Therefore, I have an extension of this superclass and it's repository interface.

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(MyCompositeIdClass.class)
public class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {

  private String myAttr;

}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface MySubClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MySubClass, MyCompositeIdClass> {
}
```

And when executing `findAll()` repository interface method, Hibernate is executing the join query with the wrong fields comparison on the join clause (inverting both PK columns):

```sql
select 
   mysuperc0_.my_first_id
   mysuperc0_.my_second_id
   mysuperc0_1_.my_attr
from
   my_super_class mysuperc0_
inner join
   my_sub_class mysuperc_0_1_
on
   my_superc0_.my_first_id = mysuperc_0_1_.my_second_id
and
   my_superc0_.my_second_id = mysuperc_0_1_.my_first_id
```

Was it configuration issues or a framework internal problem? Tried to research about inheritance issues with composite id, but got only opened issues ran from exceptions, but, in this case, I do not have exceptions, it just returns an empty array.

Comment: Have you tried removing @Id annotations from `MyCompositeIdClass` ? You may also need the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation to explicitly set

Comment: Removed the @Id annotations from the composite class and worked. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome to hear :-)